# Selecting from an honest majority population an honest majority subset with probability greater than a certain threshold?

Tags: probability

Let $n$ be a population of individuals such that at least a certain majority of them $t$ are said to be honest.

What are the values $t,k$ such that by selecting $k$ individuals at random from $n$ the majority of them is honest with probability equal to a certain $\alpha_{threshold} \in (0.5,1)$?

Intuitively, if $t$ is large then $k$ can be small, if $t$ is close to $50 \%$ then $k$ has to be large.

**First attempted answer**

$p = \frac{t}{n}$ is the probability of selecting an honest party.

$1 - p$ is the probability of selecting a dishonest party.

Let $k$ be the number of selected parties and $t'$ be the number of selected honest parties.

Then:

$$\alpha_{threshold} = P(t' > \frac{k}{2}) = P(t' = \frac{k}{2}+1) + \ldots + P(t'=k) = \binom{k}{\frac{k}{2}+1}p^{\frac{k}{2}+1}(1-p)^{\frac{k}{2}-1} + \ldots + \binom{k}{k}p^k(1-p)^0 = 
\sum_{i = 1}^{\frac{k}{2}}\binom{k}{\frac{k}{2}+i}p^{\frac{k}{2}+i}(1-p)^{\frac{k}{2}-i}
$$

From this last equation we need to find a possible $t,k$ pair such that $\alpha_{threshold} \in (0.5,1)$.

**Second attempted answer**

By adopting the hypergeomtric distribution (since each individual can be selected at most once), as suggested in the comments, and following a similar approach we obtain:

$$\alpha_{threshold} = P(t' > \frac{k}{2}) = P(t' = \frac{k}{2}+1) + \ldots + P(t'=k) = 
\frac{\binom{t}{\frac{k}{2}+1}\binom{n-t}{k-(\frac{k}{2}+1)}}{\binom{n}{k}}+
\ldots +
\frac{\binom{t}{k}\binom{n-t}{0}}{\binom{n}{k}}
= 
\sum_{i = 1}^{\frac{k}{2}}\frac{\binom{t}{\frac{k}{2}+i}\binom{n-t}{k-(\frac{k}{2}+i)}}{\binom{n}{k}}
$$

As in the previous case, from this last equation we need to find a possible $t,k$ pair such that $\alpha_{threshold} \in (0.5,1)$.

Comment: Unless $n$ is moderately large and $\alpha$ is not too close to $1,$ a fully accurate solution will rely on the *hypergeometric* distribution rather than the binomial distribution you are using.  Could you therefore indicate the ranges of $n,$ $t,$ and $\alpha$ that interest you?

Comment: I do not have specific restrictions for $n$, while the closer $t$ is to $50\%$ of $n$ the better it is, the closer $\alpha_{threshold}$ is to 1 the better it is, the smaller is $k$ the better it is. It is clearly a tradeoff, but I am not able to formulate it properly at the moment.

Comment: I see your point. For the binomial distribution, the probability is the same for every selection. For the hypergeometric distribution, each selection changes the probability for each subsequent selection because there is no replacement. This is definitely what I need.

Comment: @whuber I have sketched solution you suggested. If it is correct now I only need to find a practical way to express $t,k$ as a function of $\alpha_{threshold}$.

Comment: You would have to do that numerically.  For suitably large values of $n,t$ and non-extreme values of $\alpha,$ most people would use a Normal approximation.